# ParseQuery not retrieving all of data rows

Tags: java, parse-platform, constraints, rows

For some reason I am only getting the first few rows of data back from my query.  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.  I need to get all the objects from one column named states row by row.  But its only grabbing the first few rows. What am I doing wrong?

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> system = ParseQuery.getQuery("StatesSystem");
    //  system.fromLocalDatastore();
    system.setLimit(30);
    system.orderByAscending("SpinnersTitle");
  //  system.whereExists("System");
    system.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                int i = 0;
                choiceList = list.get(i).getString("SpinnersTitle");
                holder = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (i = 0; i < choiceList.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        choiceList = list.get(i).getString("SpinnersTitle");
                        holder.add(choiceList);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.getMessage();
                    }
                }
                if (!holder.isEmpty()) {
                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, holder);
                    Choice = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvChooseSystem);
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
                    Choice.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error retrieving system from local datastore", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You have `setLimit(30)`, is that what you really want to happen?

Comment: Smh......    face palm.....

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your ACLPermissions? Does the user have the read access to the rows you are trying to fetch?

Comment: I'm not sure whats going on.  I'm, like, 600 entries in and it just stopped.  nothing is being added to the app even it shows in the db.  I'm supposed to launch in 10 days.  I need to figure out whats going on.

Comment: SOLVED:  the problem was the limit of 100.  Changed the limit to 1000 and it runs perfectly.  Thank you all for the help  :)