# Launching next weekend and Parse objects missing once again

Tags: android, database, object, parse-platform

I am not sure if this is a database problem or not but this is the third time Parse has just stopped working.  It seems that I can get anther 200 entries into the db and then it just stops displaying the new additions on the screen.  I have force stopped the app and even deleted and reinstalled the app.  The rest of the objects run perfectly, but when i get to a certain day none of the entries forward from there show.  There was no change in the code.  Just the database.  Is there something I'm missing here????  I am supposed to launch next week and it just stopped.  Again.

I posted about this before.  Still same problem.  I resolved it before by deleting and re-entering all the objects that didn't load properly.  The code works fine.  Runs like a champ.  I now have hundreds of entries.  It is pinning and unpinning properly.  It's not pulling all the data from the db.  And i don't know why not.  Is anyone else having this problem?

[ParseQuery not retrieving all of data rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30554000/parsequery-not-retrieving-all-of-data-rows)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ParseQuery not retrieving all of data rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30554000/parsequery-not-retrieving-all-of-data-rows)

Comment: last entry that shows is dated Dec 23 and 22:57.  Nothing added today is showing

Comment: Yes,  that question is me too.  It is still an issue without resolution.  I will try deleting everything I've done today and putting it back in again.  If that does not work i will have to change the search object for 150 entries.  If i have to do that then that is what I will do but that's not fixing the problem.  Its bypassing it.  I asked the question again.   Sorry.  I am frustrated.

Comment: We would need a lot more information, at a bare minimum we would the DB Schema, the "DBAdapter" class you have written (to wrap/etc) the SQLite DB. and possibly the ContentProvider code (if you have a CP)

Comment: Do you have a DBAdapter Class? Are you able to query the DB and get a normal 'cursor' object back? Then Iterate through that cursor object and see if it returns the 'expected' values or not. Because that would let you know if the values -are- being stored in the DB properly or not.

Comment: This is for a Parse database.  I do have an application class, yes.

Comment: SOLVED:  the problem was the limit of 100.  Changed the limit to 1000 and it runs perfectly.  Thank you all for the help  :)